# jml library for android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm trying to develop an android application using msn but still have same problem in using jml library ,i did a lot of researchs .
i tried to install jml from here  http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/files/java-jml/jml-1.0b4/ 
how can i use this library e.g can i imported like any library in eclipse ? and then modify the code ?
my be i should unzip this library  and emport thier files like a java files into another project ?

can you reach out your hand ?

Answer (score 0):

after a big reasearch i found all what i need to use the msn API : here the site where you will found every detail help :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh875196.aspx
i hope for you who look to build same android apps based on msn to benefit from this